# gave all roles to user using TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I insert ID values from a Roles table for a user with user ID of 123, into Security_UserRoles table?

```
INSERT INTO [Security_UserRoles]
           ([UserID]
           ,[RoleID]
           ,[CreatedBy]
           ,[CreatedOn])
     VALUES
           (123
           ,SELECT [id] FROM [Security_Roles]
           ,'rrr.rrr'
           ,GETDATE())
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [Security_UserRoles]
           ([UserID]
           ,[RoleID]
           ,[CreatedBy]
           ,[CreatedOn])
SELECT 123, [id], 'rrr.rrr', getdate() FROM [Security_Roles]
```